# Sitecore profiling on a wild-card page

Tags: personalization, experience-profile

I have a wildcard page that loads some products. I need to present the user with a form based on page views to a product page that have a specific facet selected on the product. There are 1000s of products being served by the wildcard page and I want to personalize an experience based on "heart-healthy" products. The value is in a picker on the product item that is in a bucket, different from the wildcard item.

I can create a profile for "heart healthy" and have a profile card for it but how do I go about assigning it to items given how the content is configured? How do I assign a contact to a pattern card based on the facet?